# Solving critical points and classifying the maxima, minima and saddle points

Tags: linear-algebra, maxima-minima

I need help to find critical points of the function:
$$f(x,y,z)={(x^2+2y^2+3z^2) e ^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}}$$
Then I have to classify these critical points as local maxima/minima or saddle points.

What I would do is to take the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y, z)$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y, z)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x, y, z)$.

But now I will get

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y, z)$ = $ {2x-6e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}xz^2} $

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y, z)$ = $ {4y-6e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}yz^2} $

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x, y, z)$ = $ 3(-2e^ {-x^2-y^2-z^2}z^3+2e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}z) $

Normally I would put them in the matrix form and solve the system of equation for x, y and z.

But I don't know how to solve the system of equation with these partial derivatives. What I am doing wrong or what should be done in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Computing the partial derivatives, we then have
$$\frac{\partial f(x, y, z)}{\partial x}=-2 x  \left(x^2+2 y^2+3 z^2-1\right)e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x, y, z)}{\partial y}=-2 y  \left(x^2+2 y^2+3 z^2-2\right)e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x, y, z)}{\partial z}=-2 z  \left(x^2+2 y^2+3 z^2-3\right)e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$ which means that you need to solve
$$x  \left(x^2+2 y^2+3 z^2-1\right)=0$$
$$y  \left(x^2+2 y^2+3 z^2-2\right)=0$$
$$z  \left(x^2+2 y^2+3 z^2-3\right)=0$$ for which the solutions are quite simple
$$\{\{ 0, 0, -1\}, \{0, 0, 1\}, \{0, -1,
   0\}, \{0, 1, 0\}, \{-1, 0, 0\}, \{1, 0,
   0\}, \{0, 0, 0\}\}$$

Now, your turn.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative with respect to $x$ should be
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}=2xe^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}+(x^2+2y^2+3z^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\cdot 2x$$
by the product and chain rule.
And the other derivatives analogously.
This is $$\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}=e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}(2x-(2x(x^2+2y^2+3z^2))$$
You have to solve the system
$$2x-2x(x^2+2y^2+3z^2)=0$$
$$4y-2y(x^2+2y^2+3z^2)=0$$
$$6z-2z(x^2+2y^2+3z^2)=0$$
for $x,y,z$

Comment: Oh yeah! That's correct. But my biggest problem is now that how to proceed when I have correct partial derivatives. How to solve system of equation when there are exponents etc.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems that the only critical point is the origin $(0,0,0)$ which is a saddle point. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you prove this?

Comment: There are no exponents, since $$e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\neq 0$$

Comment: There are no global extrema!!

Comment: We don't need any computation to prove that the origin is a point of minimum. Since $(x^2+y^2+z^2)≥0$ and the other function is always $≥0$

Comment: But there are other critical points. I will write up a proof.

Comment: Saddle points are $(-1,0,0),(0,-1,0),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I wrongly said that $(0,0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: I know this, since i have done all the calculations.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $(0,0,±1)$ is max?

Comment: So the critical points therefore are (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: @MiMaKo there's more. $(±1,0,0),(0,±1,0),(0,0,±1)$

Comment: Oh no! I am puzzled. I don't know where these are coming from. I would appreciate very much if someone would show/calculate this.

Comment: Like I said "Normally I would put them in the matrix form and solve the system of equation for x, y and z." Now I just don't know how to proceed.